# Density of nilpotent numbers

Tags: number-theory, finite-groups

A natural number $n$ is *nilpotent* if every group of order $n$ is nilpotent (equivalently, a direct product of Sylow subgroups). A natural number $n$ has *nilpotent factorization* if $\ell\not\equiv1$ mod $q$ for any two prime powers $\ell$ and $q$ dividing $n$. We [know](http://www2.math.ou.edu/~shankar/papers/nil2.pdf) that a natural is nilpotent if and only if it has nilpotent factorization. Based on the folklore "almost all finite groups are $2$-groups" (which in particular means they are $p$-groups, which in particular means they are nilpotent), we might expect that nilpotent numbers have arithmetic density $1$, since otherwise nonnilpotent groups would have positive arithmetic density contrary to established belief. A little bit of [data](http://oeis.org/A056867) agrees with this idea.

Yet even if the "nilpotent number counting function" $N(x)$ satisfies $N(x)\sim x$, it wouldn't automatically mean "almost all finite groups are nilpotent," since we would also have to bound the number of ways that $p$-groups can be put together other than direct products for nonnilpotent $n$, and so we might reasonably expect $N(x)\sim x$ to be easier to prove than "almost all finite groups are nilpotent," and it seems like it would be amenable to pure number theory.

So, anybody have any ideas for establishing $N(x)\sim x$?

Comment: I don't follow the argument at the end of the first paragraph. Nonnilpotent numbers having positive density doesn't imply nonnilpotent groups having positive density. If almost all finite groups are $2$-groups then these two densities could be essentially unrelated, since the powers of $2$ have density zero.

Comment: My understanding is that that folklore is a way of phrasing the fact that the number of non-isomorphic groups of order $n$ explodes, when $n=2^\ell$. In other words, in the set of isomorphism types of finite groups (of upper bounded order) the orders that are powers of two are overpresented.

Comment: Nilpotent numbers are tabulated at https://oeis.org/A056867 --- maybe some reference cited there says something about density.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a [1983 paper of M. Ram Murty and V. Kumar Murty](http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~murty/DensityVariousClassesGroups.pdf) it is shown that if 
$f(x)$ is *any* one of:

$\bullet$ $f_1(x)$: the number of $1 \leq n \leq x$ such that every group of order $n$ is cyclic
$\bullet$ $f_2(x)$: the number of $1 \leq n \leq x$ such that every group of order $n$ is abelian
$\bullet$ $f_3(x)$: the number of $1 \leq n \leq x$ such that every group of order $n$ is nilpotent,

then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x/\log \log \log x} = e^{-\gamma}$, where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

The case of $f_1(x)$ is a 1948 result of Erdős.  The result for $f_3$ answers your question: the density of nilpotent numbers is zero...but not by much!

**Added**: These results were earlier derived by Michael E. Mays:

> Mays, Michael E.
>   Counting abelian, nilpotent, solvable, and supersolvable group orders.
>   Arch. Math. (Basel) 31 (1978/79), no. 6, 536–538.

Answer (score 3):

The density of nilpotent numbers is at most $\frac{5}{6}$, since no number divisible by $6$ can be nilpotent. Actually I would be willing to bet that the density of nilpotent numbers is $0$.

Comment: Ah, good point. My thinking is pretty wrong. Presumably this same argument could be used to keep chipping away at the density of nilpotent numbers.

Comment: It's not much harder to remove numbers divisible by $2$ which are not powers of $2$ to get $\frac{1}{2}$. From here we should remove odd numbers divisible by $3$ which are divisible by either a prime congruent to $1 \bmod 3$ or the square of a prime congruent to $2 \bmod 3$; I'm willing to bet this gets us down to $\frac{1}{3}$. And so on...

Comment: Oh, or maybe not. Hmm.